# Android : parse tag include the html content in android

Tags: android, html-parsing, saxparser

I have xml to parse in the following.

```
              <body>
                  <body.content>
                    <p>This is testing content.</p>
                    <p>This is testing content.This is testing content.This is testing content.This is testing content.This is testing content.This is testing content.This is testing content.This is testing content.This is testing content.This is testing content.</p>    
                  </body.content>
              </body>
```

I have parser method for this xml.

```
bodyTag.getChild(body_content).setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener() {

            @Override
            public void end(String body) {
                System.out.println(body);

            }
        });
```

My problem is when I parse this xml I got the following exception.

> 10-06 15:39:21.976: E/AndroidRuntime(1110): Caused by:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: android.sax.BadXmlException: Line 86:
>   Encountered mixed content within text element named 'body.content'.

The problem is that the sax parser cannot parse the `html <p>` tag. 
I want to know is there any way to parse the `html content` by sax parser.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could Use Jsoup Library : http://jsoup.org/
it`s So easy To Treat with Html/xml Tags ..

Comment: jsoup is for parsing html tag. is it? My requirement is to parse the html context which is included in the xml tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
<content><![CDATA[Your stuff here with all the <em>HTML</em> tags you can think of.]]></content>
```

I think [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html) help you as its easy to understand.

Comment: i request the server to get the xml file. I have no chance to add CDATA like this.